# innerHTML is changing the value entered

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

In an app I'm working on, I'd found that updating the DOM by rewriting a new value to `innerHTML` doesn't give the expected result.

I typed the following command in the DevTools console:

```js
document.querySelector('main-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('.unitslist').innerHTML = '<unit-bar>1</unti-bar><unit-bar>2</unti-bar>'
```

With the following result:

```html
<unit-bar>1<unit-bar>2</unit-bar></unit-bar>
```

Comment: You never close your HTML tags (because of the typos), so the browser assumes the second one must be inside the other. Also, your 2 first snippets are strictly the same. Did you mean to post different ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your strings. You open with `<unit-bar>`, but close with `</unti-bar>`. The closing tags are therefore probably ignored by the browser and it guesses where they should be, resulting in the difference you see.

Comment: thank you i didn't even noticed, and it nice to know that it could "guesses" where my closing tags should be

Answer (score 0):

so , you can solve to avoid overwriting: - 
1. get the content of the div and that add the current value to update and the existing values

DOMElem.innerHTML = DOMElem.value + (value to be updated)

Comment: the temporary solution i used is to put the entire thing inside a div